# MySQL: Join 3 Tables and multiply price with currency before ordering as new field

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables (simplified below) that I want to join and multiply bed.price with currency.oneDollar and then order as a new field priceInDollar.

hotel

```
hotelID   city             name         
2         London           Hotel-London-Inn
```

bed

```
bedID     hotelID          room            price     cur
1         2                single room     10        USD
1         2                double room     100       MXN
```

currency

```
id        cur              oneDollar         
1         USD              1                     
2         MXN              0.052605
```

---

This joins hotel and bed like I want but can´t figure out how to multiply the price to dollar as a new field and order that.

```
   SELECT hotel.*, bed.*
          FROM hotel JOIN bed
            ON hotel.hotelID = bed.hotelID
         WHERE hotel.city = 'London' ORDER BY bed.price ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another join  in the sample you get all the currency value but you can add more where condition for filter

```
     SELECT 
          hotel.*
        , bed.*
        , bed.price
        , currency.cur
        , bed.price * currency.oneDollar as priceInDollar
        FROM hotel 
        INNER JOIN bed ON hotel.hotelID = bed.hotelID
        INNER JOIN currency on currency.cur = bed.cur 
        WHERE hotel.city = 'London' 
        ORDER BY bed.price * currency.oneDollar  ASC
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to order by bed.price * currency.oneDollar

Comment: Can I do bed.price*currency.oneDollar as priceInDollar to not loose the original price value?